# CRC16-CCITT packing (Convert C code to (JS duktape))

Tags: javascript, c, protocols, crc16

How to convert this backend code to javascript?
my inputs are hex data without (0x) in one sentence like this one
("c01faa8751") is equivalent of 0xc0 0x1f 0xaa 0x87 0x51

Right data:

input1 = 0F03FEFFFE0031015505000001 crc = **91D8**
input2 = 0F03FEFFFE0031015505640001 crc = **D673**

https://gist.github.com/chitchcock/5112270 this code does not help

C code from docs This CRC is from SmartBUS (HDL):

```
void Pack_crc(unchar *ptr, unchar len){
            unint crc;
            unchar dat;
            crc=0;
            while(len--!=0){
                dat=crc>>8;
                crc<<=8;
                crc^=CRC_TAB[dat^*ptr];
                ptr++;
            }
            *ptr=crc>>8;
            ptr++;
            *ptr=crc;
}

unsigned int CRC_TAB[] = { 
            0x0000, 0x1021, 0x2042, 0x3063, 0x4084, 0x50a5, 0x60c6, 0x70e7,
            0x8108, 0x9129, 0xa14a, 0xb16b, 0xc18c, 0xd1ad, 0xe1ce, 0xf1ef,
            0x1231, 0x0210, 0x3273, 0x2252, 0x52b5, 0x4294, 0x72f7, 0x62d6,
            0x9339, 0x8318, 0xb37b, 0xa35a, 0xd3bd, 0xc39c, 0xf3ff, 0xe3de,
            0x2462, 0x3443, 0x0420, 0x1401, 0x64e6, 0x74c7, 0x44a4, 0x5485,
            0xa56a, 0xb54b, 0x8528, 0x9509, 0xe5ee, 0xf5cf, 0xc5ac, 0xd58d,
            0x3653, 0x2672, 0x1611, 0x0630, 0x76d7, 0x66f6, 0x5695, 0x46b4,
            0xb75b, 0xa77a, 0x9719, 0x8738, 0xf7df, 0xe7fe, 0xd79d, 0xc7bc,
            0x48c4, 0x58e5, 0x6886, 0x78a7, 0x0840, 0x1861, 0x2802, 0x3823,
            0xc9cc, 0xd9ed, 0xe98e, 0xf9af, 0x8948, 0x9969, 0xa90a, 0xb92b,
            0x5af5, 0x4ad4, 0x7ab7, 0x6a96, 0x1a71, 0x0a50, 0x3a33, 0x2a12,
            0xdbfd, 0xcbdc, 0xfbbf, 0xeb9e, 0x9b79, 0x8b58, 0xbb3b, 0xab1a,
            0x6ca6, 0x7c87, 0x4ce4, 0x5cc5, 0x2c22, 0x3c03, 0x0c60, 0x1c41,
            0xedae, 0xfd8f, 0xcdec, 0xddcd, 0xad2a, 0xbd0b, 0x8d68, 0x9d49,
            0x7e97, 0x6eb6, 0x5ed5, 0x4ef4, 0x3e13, 0x2e32, 0x1e51, 0x0e70,
            0xff9f, 0xefbe, 0xdfdd, 0xcffc, 0xbf1b, 0xaf3a, 0x9f59, 0x8f78,
            0x9188, 0x81a9, 0xb1ca, 0xa1eb, 0xd10c, 0xc12d, 0xf14e, 0xe16f,
            0x1080, 0x00a1, 0x30c2, 0x20e3, 0x5004, 0x4025, 0x7046, 0x6067,
            0x83b9, 0x9398, 0xa3fb, 0xb3da, 0xc33d, 0xd31c, 0xe37f, 0xf35e,
            0x02b1, 0x1290, 0x22f3, 0x32d2, 0x4235, 0x5214, 0x6277, 0x7256,
            0xb5ea, 0xa5cb, 0x95a8, 0x8589, 0xf56e, 0xe54f, 0xd52c, 0xc50d,
            0x34e2, 0x24c3, 0x14a0, 0x0481, 0x7466, 0x6447, 0x5424, 0x4405,
            0xa7db, 0xb7fa, 0x8799, 0x97b8, 0xe75f, 0xf77e, 0xc71d, 0xd73c,
            0x26d3, 0x36f2, 0x0691, 0x16b0, 0x6657, 0x7676, 0x4615, 0x5634,
            0xd94c, 0xc96d, 0xf90e, 0xe92f, 0x99c8, 0x89e9, 0xb98a, 0xa9ab,
            0x5844, 0x4865, 0x7806, 0x6827, 0x18c0, 0x08e1, 0x3882, 0x28a3,
            0xcb7d, 0xdb5c, 0xeb3f, 0xfb1e, 0x8bf9, 0x9bd8, 0xabbb, 0xbb9a,
            0x4a75, 0x5a54, 0x6a37, 0x7a16, 0x0af1, 0x1ad0, 0x2ab3, 0x3a92,
            0xfd2e, 0xed0f, 0xdd6c, 0xcd4d, 0xbdaa, 0xad8b, 0x9de8, 0x8dc9,
            0x7c26, 0x6c07, 0x5c64, 0x4c45, 0x3ca2, 0x2c83, 0x1ce0, 0x0cc1,
            0xef1f, 0xff3e, 0xcf5d, 0xdf7c, 0xaf9b, 0xbfba, 0x8fd9, 0x9ff8,
            0x6e17, 0x7e36, 0x4e55, 0x5e74, 0x2e93, 0x3eb2, 0x0ed1, 0x1ef0
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is there a specific part of the C code which you don't understand what it does? Or you don't know some specific Javascript equivalent?

Comment: Do not understand how to implement buffer (pointers) from C to js

Comment: This calculator working https://crccalc.com/

Comment: Where did you get the input you have there? Show the input and output in the code because it does not give your outputs when I try the code you have, here is my snippet https://jsfiddle.net/w4ft6v9e/2/

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/R0ZRHSv/Image-12.png

Comment: @Abdurrahim the fiddle produces the right outputs (91d8 and d673) for the right inputs. The one in the text makes no sense as `0xgh` is not a hexadecimal number, but no expected output was given for it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Converted to JS: https://jsfiddle.net/ues6nLxb/

```
function Pack_crc(hexdata){
    const CRC_TAB = [ 
        0x0000, 0x1021, 0x2042, 0x3063, 0x4084, 0x50a5, 0x60c6, 0x70e7,
        0x8108, 0x9129, 0xa14a, 0xb16b, 0xc18c, 0xd1ad, 0xe1ce, 0xf1ef,
        0x1231, 0x0210, 0x3273, 0x2252, 0x52b5, 0x4294, 0x72f7, 0x62d6,
        0x9339, 0x8318, 0xb37b, 0xa35a, 0xd3bd, 0xc39c, 0xf3ff, 0xe3de,
        0x2462, 0x3443, 0x0420, 0x1401, 0x64e6, 0x74c7, 0x44a4, 0x5485,
        0xa56a, 0xb54b, 0x8528, 0x9509, 0xe5ee, 0xf5cf, 0xc5ac, 0xd58d,
        0x3653, 0x2672, 0x1611, 0x0630, 0x76d7, 0x66f6, 0x5695, 0x46b4,
        0xb75b, 0xa77a, 0x9719, 0x8738, 0xf7df, 0xe7fe, 0xd79d, 0xc7bc,
        0x48c4, 0x58e5, 0x6886, 0x78a7, 0x0840, 0x1861, 0x2802, 0x3823,
        0xc9cc, 0xd9ed, 0xe98e, 0xf9af, 0x8948, 0x9969, 0xa90a, 0xb92b,
        0x5af5, 0x4ad4, 0x7ab7, 0x6a96, 0x1a71, 0x0a50, 0x3a33, 0x2a12,
        0xdbfd, 0xcbdc, 0xfbbf, 0xeb9e, 0x9b79, 0x8b58, 0xbb3b, 0xab1a,
        0x6ca6, 0x7c87, 0x4ce4, 0x5cc5, 0x2c22, 0x3c03, 0x0c60, 0x1c41,
        0xedae, 0xfd8f, 0xcdec, 0xddcd, 0xad2a, 0xbd0b, 0x8d68, 0x9d49,
        0x7e97, 0x6eb6, 0x5ed5, 0x4ef4, 0x3e13, 0x2e32, 0x1e51, 0x0e70,
        0xff9f, 0xefbe, 0xdfdd, 0xcffc, 0xbf1b, 0xaf3a, 0x9f59, 0x8f78,
        0x9188, 0x81a9, 0xb1ca, 0xa1eb, 0xd10c, 0xc12d, 0xf14e, 0xe16f,
        0x1080, 0x00a1, 0x30c2, 0x20e3, 0x5004, 0x4025, 0x7046, 0x6067,
        0x83b9, 0x9398, 0xa3fb, 0xb3da, 0xc33d, 0xd31c, 0xe37f, 0xf35e,
        0x02b1, 0x1290, 0x22f3, 0x32d2, 0x4235, 0x5214, 0x6277, 0x7256,
        0xb5ea, 0xa5cb, 0x95a8, 0x8589, 0xf56e, 0xe54f, 0xd52c, 0xc50d,
        0x34e2, 0x24c3, 0x14a0, 0x0481, 0x7466, 0x6447, 0x5424, 0x4405,
        0xa7db, 0xb7fa, 0x8799, 0x97b8, 0xe75f, 0xf77e, 0xc71d, 0xd73c,
        0x26d3, 0x36f2, 0x0691, 0x16b0, 0x6657, 0x7676, 0x4615, 0x5634,
        0xd94c, 0xc96d, 0xf90e, 0xe92f, 0x99c8, 0x89e9, 0xb98a, 0xa9ab,
        0x5844, 0x4865, 0x7806, 0x6827, 0x18c0, 0x08e1, 0x3882, 0x28a3,
        0xcb7d, 0xdb5c, 0xeb3f, 0xfb1e, 0x8bf9, 0x9bd8, 0xabbb, 0xbb9a,
        0x4a75, 0x5a54, 0x6a37, 0x7a16, 0x0af1, 0x1ad0, 0x2ab3, 0x3a92,
        0xfd2e, 0xed0f, 0xdd6c, 0xcd4d, 0xbdaa, 0xad8b, 0x9de8, 0x8dc9,
        0x7c26, 0x6c07, 0x5c64, 0x4c45, 0x3ca2, 0x2c83, 0x1ce0, 0x0cc1,
        0xef1f, 0xff3e, 0xcf5d, 0xdf7c, 0xaf9b, 0xbfba, 0x8fd9, 0x9ff8,
        0x6e17, 0x7e36, 0x4e55, 0x5e74, 0x2e93, 0x3eb2, 0x0ed1, 0x1ef0
    ];

    const source = [...hexdata.matchAll(/../g)].map(x => parseInt(x, 16))

    let crc = 0;
    let dat = 0;

    for (let ptr of source) {
        dat = (crc >> 8) & 0xFF;
        crc = (crc << 8) & 0xFFFF;
        crc = crc ^ CRC_TAB[(dat ^ ptr) % 256];
    }
    
    return crc;
}
```

example usage:

```
const crcString = Pack_crc('0F03FEFFFE0031015505000001').toString(16)
```

While converting you need to take into account JS has dynamic values so to keep integer values you need to always limit outputs as such for bytes you need to add "& 0xFF" and for shorts "& 0xFFFF" and so on,

Update: I see now you are going to use it with duktape.js so make it more embedded friendly as in below:

```
const CRC_TAB = new Uint16Array([...same table copied]);

function Pack_crc(hexdata) {
    
    const source = hexdata.match(/../g).map(function(x) { return parseInt(x, 16)} );
    var dat = 0;
    var crc = 0;
    for (var i in source) {
        dat = (crc >> 8) & 0xFF;
        crc = (crc << 8) & 0xFFFF;
        crc = crc ^ CRC_TAB[(dat ^ source[i]) % 256];
    }
    return crc;
}

print(Pack_crc("0F03FEFFFE0031015505000001").toString(16))
```

Comment: source ...hexdata.matchAll(/../g) means we take every two nums (like FF, A3 , 16) then map into Int mode like (256 , 123, 37) I have only   (JS  Duktape) meaning not much functionality any possibility with old school indexes do same tasks? ``` var source = hexdata;
  var crc = 0;
  var dat = 0;
  var intData;
  for (var i = 0; i < hexdata.length; i = i+2) {
      var curBuffer = hexdata[i] + hexdata[i+1];
      intData += parseInt(curBuffer, 16);
    //stopped here
      dat = (crc >> 8) & 0xFF;
      crc = (crc << 8) & 0xFFFF;
      crc = crc ^ CRC_TAB[(dat ^ i) % 256];
  }```

Comment: Please update the question, you are not asking just for JS you are asking for JS Duktape which has embedded target and typed arrays. Let me update the answer while you update the question,

Answer (score 0):

In JS `ptr` could rather be just an index to an array, let's say `pos`, for position, and the loop is simpler as a `for`. If the array contains hexadecimal digits as text, you would increment `pos` by 2. The bigger change you would need is enforcing 16-bit calculation. Bitwise operations on JS `Numbers` use 32 bits, so the 16-bit `<<` needs extra masking:

```js
//void Pack_crc(unchar *ptr, unchar len){ // becomes a single string, plus JS-like function
function Pack_crc(dataString) {
  let crc;
  let dat;
  crc = 0;
//while(len--!=0){ // becomes for() as explained above
  for (let pos = 0; pos < dataString.length; pos += 2) {
    dat = crc >> 8;
    crc <<= 8;
    crc &= 0xFFFF; // <- mask result to 16 bits
//  crc^=CRC_TAB[dat^*ptr]; // *ptr becomes 2-characters parsed as hexadecimal
    crc ^= CRC_TAB[dat ^ parseInt(dataString.substr(pos, 2), 16)];
//  ptr++; // part of for()
  }
//*ptr = crc >> 8;
//ptr++;
//*ptr = crc;
  return crc;
}

//unsigned int CRC_TAB[] = { 
const CRC_TAB = [
  0x0000, 0x1021, 0x2042, 0x3063, 0x4084, 0x50a5, 0x60c6, 0x70e7,
  0x8108, 0x9129, 0xa14a, 0xb16b, 0xc18c, 0xd1ad, 0xe1ce, 0xf1ef,
  0x1231, 0x0210, 0x3273, 0x2252, 0x52b5, 0x4294, 0x72f7, 0x62d6,
  0x9339, 0x8318, 0xb37b, 0xa35a, 0xd3bd, 0xc39c, 0xf3ff, 0xe3de,
  0x2462, 0x3443, 0x0420, 0x1401, 0x64e6, 0x74c7, 0x44a4, 0x5485,
  0xa56a, 0xb54b, 0x8528, 0x9509, 0xe5ee, 0xf5cf, 0xc5ac, 0xd58d,
  0x3653, 0x2672, 0x1611, 0x0630, 0x76d7, 0x66f6, 0x5695, 0x46b4,
  0xb75b, 0xa77a, 0x9719, 0x8738, 0xf7df, 0xe7fe, 0xd79d, 0xc7bc,
  0x48c4, 0x58e5, 0x6886, 0x78a7, 0x0840, 0x1861, 0x2802, 0x3823,
  0xc9cc, 0xd9ed, 0xe98e, 0xf9af, 0x8948, 0x9969, 0xa90a, 0xb92b,
  0x5af5, 0x4ad4, 0x7ab7, 0x6a96, 0x1a71, 0x0a50, 0x3a33, 0x2a12,
  0xdbfd, 0xcbdc, 0xfbbf, 0xeb9e, 0x9b79, 0x8b58, 0xbb3b, 0xab1a,
  0x6ca6, 0x7c87, 0x4ce4, 0x5cc5, 0x2c22, 0x3c03, 0x0c60, 0x1c41,
  0xedae, 0xfd8f, 0xcdec, 0xddcd, 0xad2a, 0xbd0b, 0x8d68, 0x9d49,
  0x7e97, 0x6eb6, 0x5ed5, 0x4ef4, 0x3e13, 0x2e32, 0x1e51, 0x0e70,
  0xff9f, 0xefbe, 0xdfdd, 0xcffc, 0xbf1b, 0xaf3a, 0x9f59, 0x8f78,
  0x9188, 0x81a9, 0xb1ca, 0xa1eb, 0xd10c, 0xc12d, 0xf14e, 0xe16f,
  0x1080, 0x00a1, 0x30c2, 0x20e3, 0x5004, 0x4025, 0x7046, 0x6067,
  0x83b9, 0x9398, 0xa3fb, 0xb3da, 0xc33d, 0xd31c, 0xe37f, 0xf35e,
  0x02b1, 0x1290, 0x22f3, 0x32d2, 0x4235, 0x5214, 0x6277, 0x7256,
  0xb5ea, 0xa5cb, 0x95a8, 0x8589, 0xf56e, 0xe54f, 0xd52c, 0xc50d,
  0x34e2, 0x24c3, 0x14a0, 0x0481, 0x7466, 0x6447, 0x5424, 0x4405,
  0xa7db, 0xb7fa, 0x8799, 0x97b8, 0xe75f, 0xf77e, 0xc71d, 0xd73c,
  0x26d3, 0x36f2, 0x0691, 0x16b0, 0x6657, 0x7676, 0x4615, 0x5634,
  0xd94c, 0xc96d, 0xf90e, 0xe92f, 0x99c8, 0x89e9, 0xb98a, 0xa9ab,
  0x5844, 0x4865, 0x7806, 0x6827, 0x18c0, 0x08e1, 0x3882, 0x28a3,
  0xcb7d, 0xdb5c, 0xeb3f, 0xfb1e, 0x8bf9, 0x9bd8, 0xabbb, 0xbb9a,
  0x4a75, 0x5a54, 0x6a37, 0x7a16, 0x0af1, 0x1ad0, 0x2ab3, 0x3a92,
  0xfd2e, 0xed0f, 0xdd6c, 0xcd4d, 0xbdaa, 0xad8b, 0x9de8, 0x8dc9,
  0x7c26, 0x6c07, 0x5c64, 0x4c45, 0x3ca2, 0x2c83, 0x1ce0, 0x0cc1,
  0xef1f, 0xff3e, 0xcf5d, 0xdf7c, 0xaf9b, 0xbfba, 0x8fd9, 0x9ff8,
  0x6e17, 0x7e36, 0x4e55, 0x5e74, 0x2e93, 0x3eb2, 0x0ed1, 0x1ef0
  //}
];

const input1="0F03FEFFFE0031015505000001";
console.log(input1,Pack_crc(input1).toString(16));
const input2="0F03FEFFFE0031015505640001";
console.log(input2,Pack_crc(input2).toString(16));
```

Comment: This is the answer (I only change let to var cause my hardware does not understand const. Thank you a lot!!!)